# Show button if root/parent element scroll up/down and hide that button if not

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to show a button if root or parent element need to be scrolled and hide a button if root/parent element not need to be scrolled ?.

For details:

- If we have an element with max-height 200px (example) and overflow-y:auto, that element will can be scrolled if childrens exceeds or greater than max-height above, and can't be scrolled if not.

Now, how to show/hide a button (example) according to root or parent element scroll.

Here is my code :

```
var contentStatusProfile = $(".main_profile");
var scrollingStatus = $(".scroll-down-status-profile");
if ( ???? ) { /* Here is my qestion about showing and hiding button corresponding parent element need to be scrolled or not */
    scrollingStatus.on('click',function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('more-up-status-profile')) {
            var lengthScroll = contentStatusProfile[0].scrollTop;
            lengthScroll -= 150;
            contentStatusProfile.animate({
                scrollTop:lengthScroll
            }, 500);
        }
        else {
            var lengthScroll = contentStatusProfile[0].scrollTop;
            lengthScroll += 150;
            contentStatusProfile.animate({
                scrollTop:lengthScroll
            }, 500);
            if(lengthScroll >= contentStatusProfile[0].scrollHeight - contentStatusProfile.height()){
                scrollingStatus.addClass('more-up-status-profile').children().addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any good answer will be appreciated. Thank.

Comment: Is that possible to share the HTML too?

Comment: Here is example for html : <div class="main_profile" style="max-height:100px; padding:20px"><ul><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li><li>lorem ipsum</li></ul></div><button class="scroll-down-status-profile">Scroll</button> , any idea ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare two different hieghts of `.main_profile`.

The jQuery [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) which include the padding.
And the JavaScript [`.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight).

You noticed that the first has `()` and not the second...
That is because the first is a jQuery method and the second is a JavaScript element property.

So those two are the ones to compare to know if there is some content to be scrolled.

I got the `click` event handler out of this if/else block.
I has to be defined separately because this if/else is only used to show/hide the button.

I also changed a bit the way you add and remove the `more-up-status-profile` class. I made it turn to red when it has the class...
Don't hesitate to put some ugly obvious colors when debugging! ;)

```js
var contentStatusProfile = $(".main_profile");
var scrollingStatus = $(".scroll-down-status-profile");

var csp_height = contentStatusProfile.outerHeight();
var csp_scrollableHeight = contentStatusProfile[0].scrollHeight;

console.log( csp_height );
console.log( csp_scrollableHeight );
console.log( csp_scrollableHeight > csp_height );

if ( csp_scrollableHeight > csp_height ) { /* Here is my qestion about showing and hiding button corresponding parent element need to be scrolled or not */
  $(".scroll-down-status-profile").show();
}else{
  $(".scroll-down-status-profile").hide();
}

scrollingStatus.on('click',function(){
  var lengthScroll = contentStatusProfile[0].scrollTop;

  if ($(this).hasClass('more-up-status-profile')) {

    lengthScroll -= 150;
    contentStatusProfile.animate({
      scrollTop:lengthScroll
    }, 500);
    
    if(lengthScroll <= 0){
      scrollingStatus.removeClass('more-up-status-profile').children().addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    }
  }
  else {

    lengthScroll += 150;
    contentStatusProfile.animate({
      scrollTop:lengthScroll
    }, 500);

    if(lengthScroll >= contentStatusProfile[0].scrollHeight - contentStatusProfile.outerHeight()){
      scrollingStatus.addClass('more-up-status-profile').children().addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }else{
      scrollingStatus.removeClass('more-up-status-profile').children().addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.main_profile{
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.more-up-status-profile{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main_profile" style="max-height:100px; padding:20px">
  <div id="test">
    <ul>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="scroll-down-status-profile">Scroll <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
```

Comment: Its Work, Thank you :-D Very much.

Comment: if my element not have a padding, am i must using height() or what ?

Comment: No... OuterHeight() includes the padding in the number returned. So that is cool, because here, you have some padding. The difference is 140px of real height where inner text is visible... Instead of 100px. If there was no padding, one or the other would return the same number.